# Adequate hash from std::any

Tags: c++, hash, stdany

Is there an adequate way in C++ to extract a hash from the data that std::any stores?
Well, or at least an object in the form of a list of bytes and its length

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? Have you considered computing the hashes you want before inserting values into the `std::any` and storing them together in something like `struct HashedValue { std::size_t hash; std::any value };`?

Comment: @alterigel: Wouldn't doing that risk undue collisions? I mean, AFAICR, type information is not hashed together with the actual value.

Comment: @einpoklum: Assuming good hashing functions, adding type information is only going to affect _which_ values collide.

Comment: @MSalters Yes. For example, the C # Dictionary considers int(1) and long (1) to be different objects

Answer (score 5):

`std::any` is a type-safe mechanism for passing an object of known type from one location to another, through an intermediary that does not need to know what that type is. Computing a hash from it is not its goal. And indeed, it wouldn't be meaningfully possible without compromising `any`'s functionality.

Hashing an object requires some knowledge of what that object is and is doing. Assuming that you can just look at the bytes of the object representation and thereby compute a meaningful hash from it is not going to end well. It might appear to work... for a while. But eventually, it's going to do the wrong thing.

You could create a type-erased type similar to `any` that requires the object to implement hashing. But `std::any` is not that type, because anyone who doesn't *want* to hash the types they put into `any` would be unable to store said object in `any`.

This is because any operation that `any` provides is an operation that all types that gets stored into `any` must *also* provide. For example, `any` is copyable, therefore `any` *cannot* store move-only types. That is an annoyance for those who want to do so, and the more functionality you dump into `any`, the more restrictive the type's ability to store "any"thing becomes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "*It’s entirely legitimate to want to use std::any as a dictionary key type*" No, it's legitimate to want to have a type-erased dictionary key type for hash containers. That `std::any` is meant to be or *ought to be* that type is another discussion entirely. I remind you that any functionality that `any` is required to have is functionality that all things you put into `any` *must have*. If `any` is hashable, then all types put into `any` must also be hashable. So even if I never use its hash functionality, my types must still be hashable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `any` doesn't require the types in question to be equality-comparable, which is why `any` cannot be equality-compared. A statically typed language is simply not an appropriate place for some kind of omni-erased-type that can forward every operation to the type-erased object. Especially if you only want that functionality to be conditionally available.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "forwarding such operations to the underlying type as required", is somewhat problematic; I agree with Nicol that it should not be `any`'s responsibility to cater to this, especially as far as you expect. That being said - there should be some way to hash type-erased values. Perhaps a hashing of their serialization?

Comment: If using std:: any to do this is problematic, can such an implementation fix it?

https://godbolt.org/z/3Wc58oarK
(I want to make an analog of Dictionary<object, ... > from C#)

Comment: @dodickgod: If we ignore the complete lack of type safety in that code, it would work to the extent outlined in my answer. Namely, it would *require* that anything you store in your wrapper be a hashable type. But don't forget that the types need to be equality comparable, since a hash table has to equality test the values. So you need to properly type-erase equality testing, particularly between objects of different types.

Comment: @NicolBolas "I think using the std_hashable concept will solve this problem"

Comment: @dodickgod: Considering that the equality testing part is the harder issue, I fail to see how that would help.

Comment: `return 0;` is a valid hash, and `return true;` is a valid equality comparison, so you can have a wrapper like `std::any`. It will be *bad* for non-equatable / non-hashable values